# SparkSQL connections issue

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark job  which is loading data from CSV files into a MySQL database.

Everything works fine but recently I noticed that Spark opens many connections during the insert stage (300+ connections). It feels like for each insert statement its opening a new connection, keep it open and at some point of time doing commit and closing the connection. Is there a way to do commit after each insert or after processing it in 10K batches and do one commit?

This would be to not open a connection for each insert. It's good if it needs to process 1K records but when you work with billions of records it's taking a lot of resources.

Comment: _that spark open many connections during insert stage (300+ connections)_ - this suggests that you have comparable number of partitions. Depending on the context you can try to coalesce / repartition before write or explicitly limit resources (for example by assigning specific queue with limited resource share). Additionally `batchsize` `option` should give you some control over the number of rows inserted per round trip. If none of that works there is always a longer path - write to disk and use `COPY` from there.

Comment: @user6910411I dont have any partitions in my  code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any operations on the dataframe the dataframe that causes shuffl, spark by default, create 200 partitions. Causes 200 connections to the database.

spark.sql.shuffle.partitions -- Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations. -- default: 200

Check the number of partitions of the dataframe using:

`df.rdd.getNumPartitions`

Re-partition the dataframe using on your frequent used column:
`df.repartition(NUMBER_OF_PARTIOTONS, col("Frequent_used_column"))`

You can also set the 'batchsize' parameter to control the number of rows to insert per round trip. This helps the performance on JDBC drivers. It defaults to 1000.

```
jdbcDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .option("batchsize", 5000)
  .save()
```